# Moving SQL Database into ram

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite Database of around 100 Mbyte. To speed up the access, I thought about moving these database first into RAM, and then read from memory directly. After I have multiple read accesses, this would speed up the application in my opinion. So, my question is how to move this database into RAM where I can access it via `sqlite3_open()`, or if my idea is bullshit and leaving the database on disk is faster than moving it into Ram via mapping.
Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean "move into RAM"? Copy 100MB to a RAM drive and lose changes if your app fails to store the file back on disk when it closes? Use SQLite as a memory-only DB and lose all changes anyway? Enable caching for SQLite queries?

Comment: Well, my database gets a lot of queries, but there won't be changes when it is loaded into RAM, so it doesn't matter when it get lost.

Answer (score 2):

See this:

https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

You'd still have to open your first database and copy the data into ram by opening up a new database in memory and inserting all the data from your copy on disk into the database you've got open in memory.

It might work faster, but you might be better off optimizing your queries or database structure.  I would look into using indices.  Another option is to try and use RowId in your where clause if you know your data is inserted into the database in order based on one of the columns.

See these as well:

http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html

Comment: Are there hints somewhere how to optimize queries or my database structure?

Comment: It also depends on what exactly is in your database.

Comment: In my database are integer values, if you're asking that.

Comment: I mean as far as the actual column names.  For example, if I have a bunch of timestamps within my database, I might be able to create a table that maps times to RowIds if the data is inserted in the order of the timestamps.

Comment: I would seriously suggest looking into creating an index for your data, you will probably see a significant performance increase.